# Why is a figure not produced when I use the Savitzky-Golay filter and matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have had this issue for a few years now but never tried to resolve it. I'm using python for data processing and occasionally I want to use a Savitzy-Golay filter to smooth out my data. At the same time I want to plot those results and I like using the Latex computer modern font for figure labels, etc. The problem occurs when I simultaneously use the Savitzy-Golay filter:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
y_filt = savgol_filter(y,51,2)
```

and the Latex font:

```
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text',usetex=True)
```

The script "freezes" and no plot is produced. If I comment out `rc('text',usetex=True)`, the script runs normally and the figure is produced; however, not with the font style I want. Also, if I comment out `y_filt = savgol_filter(y,51,2)` and leave `rc('text',usetex=True)` uncommented (and use a different data smoothing algorithm), the figure is produced. Finally, the script runs fine if I don't use any plot commands. Below are the plot commands I typically use:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text',usetex=True)

figx = 2
figy = 4
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1),(0,0))
ax1.plot(x,y_filt,color='k',lw=1)
fig.set_size_inches(figx,figy)
fig.savefig(dirFigs+'A1_extracted.pdf',dpi=600,bbox_inches='tight')
```

I'm at a loss as to why the script freezes when savgol_filter and rc are used. I'm running Python 3.8.3 through Anaconda on macOS 11.6.1.

Thank you in advance.